# How to add a category list on your page on blogger

Tags: categories, blogger

How to add a category list on my blogger page like there is a list of categories on my page example:

mysite.ml/categories
and there the categories will be list!

THANKS ANY ONE!

Answer (score 0):

Blogger automatically puts your categories on the sidebar of your blog, but if you want a whole separate page for them you could create a page and use the linking tool like this:

1. Navigate to the pages section of blogger and create a page [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cThL.jpg)
2. Add some text to the page and use the linking tool to link the url of a catagory to that text.  You can find this by navigating to one of your categories and copying the url.  It should look something like this: `https://www.yoursite.com/search/label/Your_Category` [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoTx4.jpg)
3. Do this for all your categories then save the page.  You should now have a published page with a url that looks like this: `https://www.yoursite.com/p/Your_Page.html` You can link this page in one of your posts or use the pages widget in the layout section to display it somewhere on your site.